# qgis + spatialite: convert a list of points into lines and distances

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I have a list of points stored in a spatialite database (track points from a gps log). I would like to transform these into a set of line segments and calculate the length of each segment. The original data is in CRS 4326 (WGS 84).

I think I have something that works, but I'd like to run it by folks here to make sure I'm not missing anything.

I start by importing the GPX file into QGIS by adding a vector layer. I then import this layer into a Spatiallite database. This results in a table that includes columns `track_fid`, `track_seg_id`, and `track_seg_point_id` for identifying each point (and a 3D `POINT` geometry column). During the import I transform the CRS from 4326 (WGS 84) to 26986 (NAD83 / Massachusetts Mainland), primarily because that way I get meters from `st_distance`.

I create a new table (`track_lines`) like this:

```
create table track_lines (
  id integer not null  primary key autoincrement, 
  track_fid int, 
  track_seg_id int, 
  track_seg_point_id int, 
  length int);
select addgeometrycolumn('track_lines', 'geom', 26986, 'linestring', 'XYZ');
```

Finally, I populate the `track_lines` table using the following SQL expression. In order to locate the endpoints of each line segment, I'm trying to "shift" the track points by joining on `leftside.track_seg_point_id = rightside.track_seg_point_id-1`.

```
insert into track_lines (
    track_fid, track_seg_id, track_seg_point_id, geom, length
    )
select
    a.track_fid as track_fid, 
    a.track_seg_id as track_seg_id, 
    a.track_seg_point_id as track_seg_point_id, 
    makeline(a.geom, b.geom), 
    st_distance(a.geom, b.geom)
from track_points as a join track_points as b
on (
    a.track_fid = b.track_fid 
    and a.track_seg_id = b.track_seg_id 
    and a.track_seg_point_id = b.track_seg_point_id-1
    );
```

This seems to work: the lines that result from the above query appear to match the track points. I'm a little suspicious of the join operation, because invariably when I show something like this to someone with more SQL experience they immediately reduce it in size by 70% while tripling the performance (fortunately in this case the number of points is low enough that performance isn't actually an issue).

Does this all seem sane?

Comment: QGIS @ 2.x has a tool named *Points to Paths* (note the plural Paths) that does exactly what you want to do (make sure to check on the Vertex option).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I am working with QGIS 3, which doesn't appear to have that plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, *Points to Paths* has not been updated to 3.x.  However, you can download the latest 2.x version (2.18.28) from https://qgis.org/downloads/.  Go ahead and install it alongside 3.x versions; the two versions will play nice with each other.  *Points to Paths* can be found as a 2.x plugin.  The important option to check on is labeled "Line per Vertex".